# LTE Security: What kind of cryptograpy could be used to fix layer 2?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, protocols

New attacks on LTE:

https://thehackernews.com/2018/06/4g-lte-network-hacking.html

https://www.alter-attack.net/media/breaking_lte_on_layer_two.pdf

Layer two (data link) does not guarantee the integrity of data. 
They deployed a malicious MitM relay between the mobile and the antenna to manipulate the (encrypted) payload of user data transmissions.

What kind of cryptography could be used to fix layer 2?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. But, generally, I guess one could apply some kind of AEAD scheme... or use an HMAC... or something like that.

Comment: Like in [your deleted question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189368/lte-security-new-attacks-how-to-mitigate?noredirect=1#comment373422_189368) you reference article and paper but you did not seem to have really read it. I've even pointed you to the section **Potential Countermeasure** in the paper but even then you did not seem to read it - or you did not understand it. In this section the authors talk about what is needed, i.e. integrity protection. And they also point out how it can be achieved: using MAC-then-Encrypt which is already used in other places in LTE.

Comment: @EdS please read our [ask] and [help] pages to understand how this site works. Please stop posting multiple questions in comments, and as Steffen said, you need to read the information given.

Answer (score 3):

As per the paper, you provided page 12 features a section titled "Potential Countermeasures" (Also mentioned by Steffen) - this section of the paper states what they require to prevent such attacks and they clearly point out how it can be done.

> Even though the LTE Authentication
>   and Key Agreement (AKA) is formally proven secure
>   [31], this attack is still possible due to the lack of
>   integrity protection of user plane data.
>
> While different suitable schemes exist like AES-GCM
>   (AES-Galois/Counter Mode), we focus on the MAC-then-Encrypt scheme
>   that is already used for the integrity protection of the control
>   plane. We assume that this scheme has the highest potential for being
>   adopted in the specification - [Breaking LTE on L2](https://www.alter-attack.net/media/breaking_lte_on_layer_two.pdf)

MAC-then-Encrypt is a method whereby you compute the MAC (Message Authentication Code) on the plaintext, append it to the data then encrypt hence the term "MAC-then-Encrypt". If you want more details on this see: [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)